# Web builder domain mapping for different users

Tags: codeigniter, web, dns

I have made a SAS based web builder which creates seperate urls:
`(www.abc.com/user/somename)` using codeignitor for each registered user. 
Now how i can provide facility to users, so that they can map their own domain name ?

Comment: Do you meant to say: Now you are accessing like www.abc.com/user/somename and what if you want to access like www.xyz.com/user/somename; Is that correct?

Comment: Here is the situation - Once user get registered on my web builder they will get their own website url like abc.com/user/makrwebsite and if another user sam will register then he will get his own website with url abc.com/user/samwebsite. Now both wants to use their own domain name respective of url which they got upon registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong to understand your question than this might be what you needed

> **Setting your own routing rules**
>   Routing rules are defined in your application/config/routes.php file. In it you'll see an array called $route that permits you to specify your own routing criteria. Routes can either be specified using wildcards or Regular Expressions

A typical wildcard route might look something like this:

```
$route['user/(:any)'] = "your_controller/your_function/$1";
```

Reference [URI Routing](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html). You can learn from provided link how to make dynamic url's